# Beaglebone Black - Saving Files to Desktop from Cloud9 IDE

Tags: python, file, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

I've recently acquired a Beaglebone Black (Debian Rev C) for use in a design project with a few sensors and I've been using the Cloud9 IDE (edit: just accessing 192.168.7.2:3000 in my browser to connect to the BB) to develop and upload code to the Beagle. What I've been wondering the whole time is if there's a way to instruct the Beagle to save the text files I tell it to open to the desktop of the computer I've got it attached to.

I've been using this code to create and write data from a sensor (x) to a text file:

```
    import os
    name = raw_input('name the thing: ')
    final_name = os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'boktor', 'Desktop', name + '.txt')
    data = open(name + '.txt', 'a+')
    data.write(str(x) + '\n')
    data.close()'
```

This is functional/useful for now, but my issue is that this doesn't save to my computer, it just saves in the Cloud9 menu/sidebar in the same folder as the code I created. How is this possible? Shouldn't there be an error involving os.path.join()? The file is definitely not on my desktop.

Is there a better way to tell the Beaglebone to place this file on my computer's desktop or another folder (within the beaglebone perhaps?)

Answer (score -1):

You can download files via `File` > `Download Files`. For more info, see [Download Files from Cloud9](https://docs.c9.io/docs/download-files).

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using the Cloud9 IDE as a means of programming and accessing the Beaglebone. I know I can download using  use File > Download Project, but that gives me everything on the beaglebone.That's not the functionality I want. I specifically want to make my beaglebone place the file it creates on my computer's desktop.

Comment: I don't think I understand enough to help you out further than this but since Cloud9 IDE is a cloud IDE you can login from your desktop and save there with this method or perhaps there's some way to save to the desktop through the Beaglebone. Again, your use case is still pretty confusing to me and I don't think I know enough about the BB to give you a good answer so try working with the info I've given you or else you might try editing your original post to make it more clear what you're trying to do.